# is it possible to save a selection of several layers in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So let me explain the issue. Say I have layers A-Z I select layers A, B, F, R for example, make a change to those layers, but then I go back to doing other things so I deselect those layers. Is there anyway I could have saved that selection of layers, so that I could then comeback later and make more adjustments to them, or do I just have to reselect them each time? anybody know?

p.s. it isn't an option to group the layers as they're from all over the document tree and grouping them doesn't make sense for moving them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option aside from grouping them would be to "link" layers.

From the Layers window make your selection, right click and chose "Link Layers". This will allow you to move the objects as one but still give you the ability to edit each separately.

Comment: Hi roleat thnks, but what I'm looking to do isn't move them, but rather change the font. (and the character styles doesn't work on my system unfortunately). I wish I could save a selection of layers, there are so many times it seems I have to reselect the same group of things.

Comment: If that's the case then either create an "Action" to run or try to rearrange your objects to they are grouped in a reasonable order. 

Text layers can be mass edited.

Comment: "create an "Action" to run" ahh brilliant. For some reason I didn't know actions could record selections. And it's not that they're not grouped correctly, if you think about it say I want to modify headers, from paragraphs, it makes more sense to group the headers with their paragraphs than with the other headers. Any thanks for the answer, actions does the trick. Cheers.

Comment: (saved me a lot of time by the way) lol...

Comment: No worries! Enjoy your photoshop'n :)